# Inequality using order relation

Tags: inequality, induction, binomial-theorem, number-comparison

$1^{2n} +2^{2n} +3^{2n} \ge 2\times 7^n$
This question is from An excursion in mathematics in the section of order relation
I tried using induction,tried to prove
$1^{2n} +2^{2n+1} \ge 2\times 7^n$ which is not true, tried to prove left side always divides right side

Comment: Is the last term on the left really just $3^2$ or is it $3^{2n}$ ?

Comment: I've edited the question as-is but it must be $3^{2n}$. Otherwise it fails already for $n=2$: the left side is $26$ and the right side is $98$. On a different point: have you tried to divide the entire inequality by $3^{2n}$? The left side will be $>1$; how about the right side?

Comment: It's 2n sorry for the mistake

Comment: Isnt $9^n>2\times7^n$ after $n>2$?